# C language, segmentation fault(core dump created)

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, typedef, dynamic-memory-allocation

It give me core dump error after I have create a child in my binary tree, the if condition work perfectly, but when I try to pass the sx child as parameter it give error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodes *node;

struct nodes{
    int dato;
    node sx;
    node dx;
};

node build(node n){
    printf("Insert the value: ");
    scanf("%d",&n->dato );

    char s[5];
    printf("build  a child? ");
    scanf("\n%s",s);

    if(s[0]=='l')
        build(n->sx);


    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    system("clear");
    node root=(node)malloc(sizeof(node));
    root=build(root);
    printf("\n\nvalue: %d\n", root->dato);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `n->sx` is uninitialized.

Comment: This is obviously wrong, `node root=(node)malloc(sizeof(node));`. You already have a `node`, that's what `root` is. So why are you allocating space for one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the problem is in the memory allocation.

```
 node root=(node)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

which represents

```
struct nodes * node = (struct nodes *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodes *));
```

while, it should have been

```
struct nodes * node = malloc(sizeof(struct nodes));
```

So, essentially, you're allocating *way* less memory (just for a pointer) than the expected (a whole variable).

Then, once fixed, at a later point, `build(n->sx);` will also invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as you're trying to pass an unitialized pointer to function, and dereferencing it.

That said, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Casting malloc or not is a matter of style, >1000 upvotes still don't make it true that it would be an error. Please don't be dogmatic.

Comment: @Ctx That's why I did not discuss that here, added the link, and said _please_. Rest, upto the reader. :)

Comment: If you would be as neutral as you claim, why don't you write "Please see this discussion about casting the return value of malloc() and family in C"